# Populate global function pointers in shared library (Solaris, Sun Studio)

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, solaris, sunstudio, dlsym

I am creating a small C++ wrapper shared library around a Fortran 95 library. Since the Fortran symbols contain `.` in the symbol name, I have to use `dlsym` to load the Fortran function into a C++ function pointer.

Currently, I have a bunch of global function pointers in header files:

```
// test.h
extern void (*f)(int* arg);
```

and I populate them in the corresponding C++ file:

```
// test.cc
void (*f))(int* = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(int*>(dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "real_f.symbol_name_");
```

Questions:

1. If I do it this way, **when are these pointers populated?**
2. Can I assume them to be loaded in my executable that loads this library?
3. In particular, **can I use these functions in statically created objects** in my executable or other libraries? Or does this suffer from the *static initalization order fiasco*?
4. If the above way is not correct, **what is the most elegant way of populating these pointers** such that they can be used in static objects in executables and other libraries?

I am using the Sun Studio compiler on Solaris, if that makes a difference, but I would also be interested in a solution for GCC on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does the line

```
f = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(int*)>(dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "real_f.symbol_name_"));
```

occur in `test.cc`?  The pointer will be initialized when the line is
executed (which of course depends on when the function which contains it
is called).  Or did you mean to write

```
void (*f)(int* ) = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(int*>(dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "real_f.symbol_name_");
```

?  In this case, the pointer will be initialized during static
initialization.  Which means that you still have order of initialization
issues if you try to use the pointers in the constructor of a static 
object.

The classical solution for this would be to use some sort of singleton:

```
struct LibraryPointers
{
    void (*f)(int* );
    //  ...
    static LibraryPointers const& instance()
private:
    LibraryPointers();
};

LibraryPointers const&
LibraryPointers::instance()
{
    static LibraryPointers theOneAndOnly;
    return theOneAndOnly;
}

LibraryPointers::LibraryPointers()
    : f( reinterpret_cast<void(*)(int*)>(dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "real_f.symbol_name_")) )
    , //  initialization of other pointers...
{
}
```

Then wrap the library in a C++ class which uses this structure to get
the addresses of the pointers.

And one last remark: the `reinterpret_cast` you are trying to do isn't
legal, at least not formally.  (I think that both Sun CC and g++ will
accept it, however.)  According to Posix, the correct way to get a
pointer to function from `dlsym` would be:

```
void (*f)(int* );
*reinterpret_cast<void**>(&f) = dlsym(...);
```

This doesn't lend itself to initializations, however.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I indeed meant to write it as you said. I will correct the question.
I know that I will have problems with other static objects in the same library, but is that also true in other libraries that use this library?

Comment: I would really like to avoid the singleton solution, I had thought of this also..

Comment: @lytenyn Other libraries shouldn't have a problem **if** they are loaded after your library has been loaded.  (And of course, if they are loaded before, the global symbol with the pointer to the function isn't available.)